# jQuery TableSorter Custom Currency Parser

Tags: jquery, parsing, currency, tablesorter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery tablesorter - Not sorting column with formatted currency value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027438/jquery-tablesorter-not-sorting-column-with-formatted-currency-value)

This http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-meta-parsers.html is definitely awesome for me.

However, I am italian, so I want to display my currency value like this:

> € 12.345,67

instead of this

> $ 12345.67

I read something about custom parsers, but I don't know exactly how to proceed.

Can you help me?

Comment: I have updated my answer below

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11299126/353288

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the header with the currency column to

```
<th class="{sorter: 'commaDigit'}">Cost</th>
```

And add the following custom parser :

```
jQuery.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "commaDigit",
    is: function(s) {
        return /^[0-9]?[0-9,\.]*$/.test(s);
    },
    format: function(s) {
        return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(/,/g, ''));
    },
    type: "numeric"
});
```

Comment: sorry guy... you missed a COMMA ;) It doesn't work because of that!

Comment: Ahh ok - i understand now - let me take another look ...

Comment: @Fabio B. You marked me down because I read your question wrong ? perhaps if you mentioned the word COMMA in your question you would have got more of a response !!!!!

Comment: my mistake, sir ;-) I will try and let you know, thank you!

Comment: it gives me this js error: table is undefined: var c = table.config;

Comment: @Fabio B. = updated - try that again ! sorry !

Comment: thanks a lot! is it supposed to work with strings like "- 12.00", "0.25", "+ 3.46" ? How can I modify this parser?

Comment: You will need to rewrite the regular expression to remove the . and the ,