# jQuery tablesorter - Not sorting column with formatted currency value

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

jQuery 1.7.1 & tablesorter plugin - I have a currency column with thousand separators and values like $52.00  $26.70  $100.00  $50.00  $1,002.00  $1,102.00. When I try to sort getting sorted in the following way,

```
   $1,002.00  
   $1,102.00
   $26.70
   $50.00
   $52.00
   $100.00
```

Need values like,

```
   $26.70
   $50.00
   $52.00
   $100.00
   $1,002.00  
   $1,102.00
```

Tried many solutions mentioned here, but no success.

Comment: Why don't you remove the commas, then add them back in?

Comment: @JosephSilber Not sure how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Check this out.  It's EU mode but you'll be able to figure it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403726/jquery-tablesorter-plugin-comma-decimals

Comment: @SyAu - To remove the commas, simply use `str.replace(/,/g, '')`. To add them back in, see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761660/inserting-commas-into-numbers-for-both-objects-and-input-text-fields#answer-8761929).

Comment: @BrentAnderson I followed that link and I found a fix, please see my comments under the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Tablesorter allows you to define "[custom parsers](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html)" for things like this.

```
// add parser through the tablesorter addParser method 
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'thousands',
    is: function(s) { 
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) {
        // format your data for normalization 
        return s.replace('$','').replace(/,/g,'');
    }, 
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'numeric' 
}); 

$(function() {
    $("table").tablesorter({
        headers: {
            6: {//zero-based column index
                sorter:'thousands'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

You may have to tweak the format function, which I've not tested.

Comment: I tested your solution, it works. Thanks. I have selected your answer as accepted. I have lot of pages with currency value like above, so I put a fix in the jquery.tablesorter.min.js under format function of ts.addParser({id:"currency" ... with s=s.replace(',', '');  as proposed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403726/jquery-tablesorter-plugin-comma-decimals), thanks 'Brent Anderson' for this. Thanks 'Joseph Silber' for your suggestion as well.

Comment: this fails with multiple '.'s or ','s ie 9.2 (92) > 2.2.9 (229)

Comment: @Blowsie, that's no great surprise as the data no longer conforms to 'thousands' formatting rules. You would need to develop a parser to specifically handle your data.

Answer (score 25):

If you just want to fix currency numbers (quickest):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("table").tablesorter({
        textExtraction: function(node){ 
            // for numbers formattted like €1.000,50 e.g. Italian
            // return $(node).text().replace(/[.$£€]/g,'').replace(/,/g,'.');

            // for numbers formattted like $1,000.50 e.g. English
            return $(node).text().replace(/[,$£€]/g,'');
         }
    })
</script>

<td><span>£80,000.00</span></td>
```

I don't like these 3 other proposed solutions on StackOverflow:

1. 'Use custom parser and apply in the table sort init' - not reusable for lots tables
2. 'Use custom parser and apply with table cell's class' - dirty markup
3. 'Fix TableSorters currency sort in source' - hassle for future upgrades

Comment: If you want to add "Kg" in this textExtraction creates a bug to the rest of columns when you try to filter by the letter "g". The column won't be able to filter this "g". So I would recommend the "addParser" solution from above.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to fix all data types (most flexible):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("table").tablesorter({
            textExtraction: function(node){ 
                var cell_value = $(node).text();
                var sort_value = $(node).data('value');
                return (sort_value != undefined) ? sort_value : cell_value;
            }
        })
    })
</script>

<td data-value="2008-04-01">01 Apr 2008</td>
<td>Alice</td>
<td data-value="80.00"><span>£80.00</span></td>
```

This has the advantage of separating display data from the sort data, more reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Following the same idea proposed by @Ownen, since TableSorter v2.16.0, you can use the `data-text` attribute directly, without the need to declare your own `textExtraction` function (more info [here](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#Configuration)):

```
<td data-text="2008-04-01">01 Apr 2008</td>
<td>Alice</td>
<td data-text="80.00"><span>£80.00</span></td>
```

This attribute work with other widgets too, like [math](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-math.html).

Note: in order to make it work with the [output widget](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-output.html), you need to declare the `output_dataAttrib` option:

```
$('#table').tablesorter({
    widgets: ["output"],
    widgetOptions : {
       output_dataAttrib: 'data-text'
    }
});
```